# Is the Schrodinger Equation easier to solve in Spherical Coordinates when dealing with the Hydrogen Atom?

Tags: physics

Recently, I have been researching the Schrodinger Equation. I am now attempting to derive the solution to the equation for the Hydrogen Atoms potential energy function. What I am wondering is that whether it is easier to do a coordinate change in the Schrodinger equation to make it Spherical.
I am specifically working with this version:
$${ih}\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t}=[\frac{-h^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V(\mathbf r, t)]\psi$$
Additionally, I am wondering if there are any Spherical Harmonics you could pull out of this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's much easier in spherical coordinates. One of the outcomes is that a stationary solution will have constant angular momentum. That implies that the solutions will be spherical harmonics multiplied by a radial function. I am not sure if anyone published a solution derived in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I was actually thinking along the same lines, but I got spooked by how messy spherical coordinates can get.

Comment: For all central potentials just use spherical coordinates. It will help separate the wave function into spherical harmonics and a radial function

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39680/why-is-there-a-need-of-polar-coordinates-to-solve-the-schr%C3%B6dinger-wave-equation